# Vuejs: data list not accessible from template in another template

Tags: javascript, vue.js

So I have this set-up, which crashes on v-for construct of table-component. It shows an error: "Property or method "tablesList" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render". If I omit v-for table-component renders. If I access this data from "container" component all is fine. So the problem is in accessing data from child template in parent template.

What am I doing wrong?

```
let container = Vue.component("container", {
        props: ["item"],
        template: `<div class="container">

            <table-component v-for="item in tablesList"></table-component>
          </div>`
      });

let table = Vue.component("table-component", {
        props: ["item"],
        template: `<div class="table">
            this is a table
          </div>`
      });

      let app = new Vue({
        el: "#app",
        data() {
          return {
            containersList: [],
            tablesList: [{item:'item'}]
          };
        },
        methods: {
          anyMethod() {

          }
        }
      });
    </script>
```

Comment: Why dont you add `tablesList` to your `container` component instead of `table-component`?

Comment: tablesList is in Vue instance not in table-component. Or am I getting you wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `tablesList` in `container component` **But** you defined it in `app`.

You need to add `tablesList` in `container` like below,

```
let container = Vue.component("container", {
    props: ["item"],
    data: () => {
       return {
          tablesList: [{item:'item'}]
       }
    },
    template: `<div class="container">
                <table-component v-for="item in tablesList"></table-component>
              </div>`
    });
```

**NOTE:** Use `v-bind:key` when use `v-for`.

Comment: aha, that makes sense. Let me check it out. Yet upvote for you :)

Comment: Alright! It worked. I get a bunch of new errors, but I'll figure them out later. Thanks mate! ))

Answer (score 1):

You need to define tablesList in props => https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-to-Child-Components-with-Props

Comment: Could you explain how to do it, please?